# R: How to simply compare values of columns in 2 data frames

Tags: r

I am comparing two data frames: [FU](https://www.dropbox.com/s/78f01ffpsffp3ym/test.FU.LINA.table?dl=0) and [FO](https://www.dropbox.com/s/beiy2x54mk7ga6t/test.FO.LINA.table?dl=0)
Here are short samples of what they look like

```
"Model_ID" "FU_Lin_Period" "FU_Growth_rate"
2 0.72127 0.0093333
3 0.69281 0.015857
4 0.66735 0.021103
5 0.64414 0.024205
6 0.62288 0.026568
7 0.60318 0.027749
8 0.58472 0.028161
9 0.56734 0.028008
10 0.55085 0.027309
11 0.53522 0.026068
12 0.52029 0.024684
13 0.50603 0.022866
14 0.49237 0.020991
15 0.47928 0.018773
```

```
"Model_ID" "FO_Lin_Period" "FO_Growth_rate"
7 0.44398 0.008868
8 0.43114 0.01674
9 0.41896 0.023248
10 0.40728 0.028641
11 0.39615 0.032192
12 0.38543 0.03543
13 0.37517 0.03692
14 0.36525 0.038427
15 0.35573 0.038195
```

As you can tell, they do not have all the same `Model_ID`

Basically, what I want to do is go through every `Model_ID` in the two tables, compare whether FU or FO's growth rate is larger for a given model ID, and...

- if FU's is larger (or FU exists for the model number and FO does not), place the model number in a vector called `selected_FU`
- if FO's is larger (or FO exists for the model number and FU does not), place the model number in a vector called `selected_FO`

Is there a way to do this without using loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*data.table* alternative using similar logic to the *tidyverse* answer.

Replace `NA`s with `-Inf`inity, do the comparison of the two `FU/FO_Growth_rate` variables, flag which group had the larger value, and select the `Model_ID` into the variables requested.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(FU)
setDT(FO)

out <- merge(FU, FO, by="Model_ID", all=TRUE)[,
    "gr_sel" := c("FO","FU")[(nafill(FU_Growth_rate, fill=-Inf) >
                              nafill(FO_Growth_rate, fill=-Inf)) + 1],
]
selected_FU <- out[gr_sel == "FU", Model_ID]
selected_FO <- out[gr_sel == "FO", Model_ID]
```

Data used:

```
FU <- read.table(text="Model_ID FU_Lin_Period FU_Growth_rate\n2 0.72127 0.0093333\n3 0.69281 0.015857\n4 0.66735 0.021103\n5 0.64414 0.024205\n6 0.62288 0.026568\n7 0.60318 0.027749\n8 0.58472 0.028161\n9 0.56734 0.028008\n10 0.55085 0.027309\n11 0.53522 0.026068\n12 0.52029 0.024684\n13 0.50603 0.022866\n14 0.49237 0.020991\n15 0.47928 0.018773", header=TRUE)
FO <- read.table(text="Model_ID FO_Lin_Period FO_Growth_rate\n7 0.44398 0.008868\n8 0.43114 0.01674\n9 0.41896 0.023248\n10 0.40728 0.028641\n11 0.39615 0.032192\n12 0.38543 0.03543\n13 0.37517 0.03692\n14 0.36525 0.038427\n15 0.35573 0.038195", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was not specific enough. I want to put `Model_ID` in `selected_FU` and `selected_FO` not the growth rate. I am glad that your solution works though w/o tidyverse, unlike the other solution.

Comment: @Woj - see my update, that should cover what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure, what am I supposed to replace `FU_Growth_rate` and `FO_Growth_rate` with, since I do not have declared variables for these?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Those are just references to your variable names in your data (I didn't download the files, I just used what you copied and pasted here). If you're wondering what I did, `nafill` replaces the `NA` values with negative infinity so they are always smaller in any comparison.

Comment: I understand, thanks. It is weird though, `selected_FU` comes out to `0` with its snippet of code.

Comment: @Woj - it should give results for both selections - see the data I used now added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `reader`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)

FU <- read_table2("test.FU.LINA.table")
FO <- read_table2("test.FO.LINA.table")

df_compared <- 
  full_join(FU, FO, by = "model_id") %>% 
  replace_na(list(fo_growth_rate = -1, fu_growth_rate = -1)) %>%
  mutate(select_fufo = if_else(fu_growth_rate >= fo_growth_rate, true = "fu", false = "fo"))

df_compared
# A tibble: 6,166 x 6
   model_id fu_lin_period fu_growth_rate fo_lin_period fo_growth_rate select_fufo
      <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>      
 1        2         0.721        0.00933        NA           -1       fu         
 2        3         0.693        0.0159         NA           -1       fu         
 3        4         0.667        0.0211         NA           -1       fu         
 4        5         0.644        0.0242         NA           -1       fu         
 5        6         0.623        0.0266         NA           -1       fu         
 6        7         0.603        0.0277          0.444        0.00887 fu         
 7        8         0.585        0.0282          0.431        0.0167  fu         
 8        9         0.567        0.0280          0.419        0.0232  fu         
 9       10         0.551        0.0273          0.407        0.0286  fo         
10       11         0.535        0.0261          0.396        0.0322  fo         
# ... with 6,156 more rows

selected_fu <- df_compared %>% filter(select_fufo == "fu") %>% .$model_id
selected_fo <- df_compared %>% filter(select_fufo == "fo") %>% .$model_id
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was not specific enough. I want to put the model number in `selected_fu` and `selected_fo` not the growth rate

Comment: Also, since I can't install `tidyverse` what libraries do I need for this? This solution does not work

Comment: I updated the answer. The packages are `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `reader`.